# Gradle DSL method not found: 'testCompile()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to build a project a Project in Android Studio. When I run the app, I get this error:

```
Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'testCompile()'
Possible causes:
-The project 'AccurateCalculator' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
-Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.2 and sync project.The project 'AccurateCalculator' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
-Open Gradle wrapper file.The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin
```

`build.grade` of the project has the following code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` of the module has the following code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "calculator.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine.jar')
    compile files('libs/arity-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/ejml-0.21.jar')
    compile files('libs/slider.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the warning suggests, upgrading the plugin to `2.3.2` should resolve the issue:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faced this issue and couldn't fix it by changing the gradle file:

I have faced this issue after my MAC was formatted. The fix for me was changing the OS language back to english. I suggest trying that.

[For changing OS language (MAC)](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=43834)